# Fabricjs tainted canvas when I try to add an image from my server

Tags: .htaccess, canvas, fabricjs

I want to add an image from my server to canvas and then export it. But I get this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

I've been in this dilemma for over a week and haven't found a solution.

Here is what I've tried:

1. To set the cross origin to anonymous:

   ```
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function () {
       var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
           scaleX: 1,
           scaleY: 1
       })
       canvas.add(imgInstance);
   }
   img.src = event.target.result;
   img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
   img.src = 'logo.svg'; // I also tried with full url http://example.com/logo.svg
   ```

No success. The image is applied to canvas but I can't export it.

2. Same as 1) but using fabricjs function:

   ```
   var src = "logo.svg"; // also tried with http://example.com/logo.svg

   fabric.util.loadImage(src, function(img) {
       var object = new fabric.Image(img);
       object.set({ 
           left: 0, 
           top: 0
       });
       object.hasRotatingPoint = true;
       object.scaleX = object.scaleY = 1;
       canvas.add(object);
       canvas.renderAll();    
   }, null, {crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'});
   ```
3. With server side (php). **Not recommended. BAD IDEA**. Works partially but is not ok.

   ```
   <?php
       $path = 'http://nistorcristian.com/comixer/logo.svg';
       $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       $data = file_get_contents($path);
       $base64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
   ?>

   fabric.Image.fromURL('<?=$base64?>', function(obj2) {
       canvas.add(obj2);
   });
   ```
4. Set the .htaccess:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   </IfModule>
   ```

   OR:

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.(svg|svgz)$">
     SetEnvIf Origin »
       "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(example\.com)$" origin_is=$0
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
5. I tried to define in my php file the header:

   ```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   ```

Still no luck. Anything would be great :) 
Thank you

Comment: The `img.src = event.target.result;` should not be there (but may not solve the problem). Does the SVG reference external files (foreign objects, style sheets etc.) ?

Comment: No ... But I read some more stuff and I saw that currently it is not supported to export a canvas after it was tainted with a SVG. (only in Firefox it works). With a jpeg or png it works in all browsers ok but not with a SVG. Maybe in future. Thank you for your answer Ken

Answer (score 1):

Ok ... I just found out. I saw on this demo from fabricjs (http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/) that they are able to export the svg ... So I looked into their code and I saw this:

```
var addShape = function(shapeName) {

    console.log('adding shape', shapeName);

    var coord = getRandomLeftTop();

    fabric.loadSVGFromURL('../assets/' + shapeName + '.svg', function(objects, options) {

      var loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

      loadedObject.set({
        left: coord.left,
        top: coord.top,
        angle: getRandomInt(-10, 10)
      })
      .setCoords();

      canvas.add(loadedObject);
    });
  };
```

I just changed it to work on my script and now it is ok. Finally

Comment: what happen to this url "http://example.com/logo.svg"  how you apply this?